# Report Builder 3.0 Limitations

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, reportbuilder

I am building an application and the client is asking for reports. Normally we would create the reports for them using reporting services. We are wanting to give the client report builder and let them build there own reports. Some of these reports can be complex and I am not 100% sure how far report builder will take us.

Before we decide if it’s worth giving the client report builder. What are the limitations of report builder? What type of report is it no good for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it is fine for creating and managing reports to be placed on the report server.   You obviously cannot use it for .rdlc reports.  For most standard users and power users it will be just fine and do what they need, and will not require the entire VS IDE shell that comes with SQL Server (BIDS).

Just remember, if the client is asking to manage their own reports, it's kind of an "all or nothing" situation.  You cannot limit their access to the data.  Make sure they have a read only reporting account set up on the server.  Any reports you create for them originally  are backed up.

Train up time may vary depending on the technical level of the end-user expected to use the tool.